# Undo Redo In Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a big object lined in $rootScope (say > 100 objects and each having hierarchy of objects/array again), I want to $watch entire $rootScope with deepWatching(i.e. turning 3rd parameter of $watch to TRUE).

But the problem here is, $watch returns 2 objects (i.e. one Old RootScope and Modified RootScope). Then I have to do a process of checking what attribute of object changed in $rootScope and its hierarchy to PUSH it into stack.

Do we have an easy way out to get the exact attribute changed while watching a $scope?

```
$scope.$watch($rootScope, function(oldObj, newObj){

   //all I want here is exactly what attribute changed, NOT entire objects!

}, true);
```

Alternatively, I could add watch on each attribute of the Object but it appears to be extremely expensive.

What is the best way to achieve undo/redo in angular js?

**Note** :-

1. angular-history doesnt suit my need because I want to watch all attributes of object, which may also contain other objects and array.
2. I'm certain watching entire $rootScope is not a good idea either, but I have aimed to build an UI which has several grids, drag n drop, might contain form, elements can be deleted. So I want to build an overall solution to stack the changes and undo it on CTRL + Z. Imagine replicating desktop version of Photoshop.

Answer (score 5):

Undo/redo is based on the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). And yes, there will be a lot of watches; such a rich functionality does not come cheap.

Just for the fun of it, here is a simple (but quite usable and extensible) implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/sYc4e/1/

A command is an interface for objects that know how to apply and rollback a change:

```
function XxxCommand() {
    // implementation specific
}
Command.prototype.execute = function() {
    // implementation specific
};
Command.prototype.rollback = function() {
    // implementation specific
};
```

Usage: You decorate the `<input>`s with a directive:

```
<input name="name" undoable ng-model="data.name" />
```

And wrap them with an element (e.g. the `<form>`) with the `undo-support` directive:

```
<form undo-support>
```

The link function of `undoable` listens for a change in the `<input>` and registers a command with the `undoableSupport`. The controller of `undoableSupport` keeps track of the command list.

Answer (score 4):

There's also an undo/redo library called [Angular-Chronicle](https://github.com/Blitzen/Angular-Chronicle). For myself at least, it was a better option than angular-history.

Answer (score 2):

The library [angular-history](https://github.com/decipherinc/angular-history) provides undo/redo.

<s>Currently not maintained. Most recent fork seems to be https://github.com/domoritz/angular-history.</s>

Comment: If anyone downvotes, please provide the reason in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

instead of watching the whole $rootScope or for that matter any one object that contains a lot of items which in turn contain a lot of items requiring you to iterate through that nested array on every digest, I would use an array(using it as a queue) of changes that are applied to the original data model and a variable that points to a current location in that queue.

I would put that array and that variable in a service and then change that index whenever undo/redo happens. You can watch that variable from everywhere that you need to respond to these changes, like directives

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

Correct me if I am wrong, So you mean to say save the entire $rootScope into array stack and then move pointer to and fro, that was my initial thought but eventually browser will hang because $rootScope can be a huge data structure to save as a whole. Pushing multiple instance of it might affect performance big time!

Comment: No, not the whole $rootScope, just an object containing other objects that may change.

Comment: $rootScope.ETC is the main object to be watched, now "ETC" can contain 100 more objects, n each object can contain several other objects. I need to watch entire ETC. But how do I know precisely which attribute changed in the heirarchy?

Comment: Im assuming your when you are displaying the contents of that object on your page, you are associating its values with the dom element somehow, either through ng-model or directives, etc. Whenever that user changes the value of that dom element you can have your directive set a dirty flag and record the change in a way that will allow you to associate it with the original value

Comment: Yes, correct. My application consists of several directives and I can put $watch at directive level too! But the problem is that the directive can also contain multiple objects n all. So again the same problem, it would return me entire object changed. So finally I will end up re-cursing through the object to find the exact property changed! 
Imagine this recursive function getting executed every time for even a key stroke. This would be very expensive when we have 50 directives and each directives having at-least 50 Objects.

Comment: So all I need is to know is, does angular provide anything that can get me the "exact attribute changed" in a vast object if the entire object is watched? 
This way in one shot I can get the changed attribute and also track its hierarchy in the object and then log both in a stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think the LazyJsonUndoRedo is what you're looking for.

https://github.com/azazdeaz/LazyJsonUndoRedo

From the readme:

> A 'drop in' history handler with automatic undo/redo functionality for nested javascript objects, using ES6 Object.observe() or Polymer shim.

http://dailyjs.com/2014/07/18/lazy-json-undo/

Comment: For anyone coming to this answer in 2016 or later: It's not angular-specific, it's for plain objects, and `Object.observe` is an abandoned effort. A modern non-Angular implementation would use [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) instead.